# VK API - получение полного списка участников сообщества

Tags: php, массивы, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

**Задача:**

Получить список участников сообщества и занести его в БД. И еще, перед добавлением в БД, очистить список от забаненых пользователей.

**Что я смог:**

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$token = "токен";
//Получаем список пользователей
$page = 0;
$limit = 1000;
do {
$offset = $page * $limit;
    //Получаем список пользователей
    $members = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers?group_id=porneffect&v=5.16&offset=$offset&count=$limit&fields=sex,bdate,city,country,photo_200_orig,photo_max_orig&access_token=$token"),true);

    //Спим
  //  sleep(1);

    //Вот тут я хз
    foreach($members['response'] as $user ) {
        print_r($user);
    }
 //   sleep(1);

    //Увеличиваем страницу
    $page++;
} while($members['response']['count'] > $page * $limit );
```

Очистка от забаненых:

```
for($i=0;$i<$members['response']['count'];$i++)if($members['response']['items']["$i"]['deactivated'])unset($members['response']['items']["$i"]);
```

**Что я не смог:**

Получить больше 1000 участников.
Проблема в том, что за 1 запрос можно получить максимум 1000 участников.
Т.е. нам нужно увеличивать offset на 1000 при каждом запросе и в конце объединить массивы, но сделать это я не в силах, поэтому прошу помощи у Вас.

Документация: https://vk.com/dev/groups.getMembers

**Еще вопрос:**

Как оптимизировать этот код, чтобы получение списка происходило максимально быстро?

Comment: Вот, что получилось: http://pastebin.com/kH9TsnmG

Выполнение при ~1000 участников в группе заняло 1.42 sec

Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$token = "token";
$page = 0;
$limit = 1000;
$users = array();
do {
  $offset = $page * $limit;
  //Получаем список пользователей
  $members = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getMembers?group_id=porneffect&v=5.16&offset=$offset&count=$limit&fields=sex,bdate,city,country,photo_200_orig,photo_max_orig&access_token=$token"),true);

  //Спим
  sleep(1);

  foreach($members['response']['items'] as $user ) {
    $users []= $user; // добавляем юзера к юзерам
  }
  //Увеличиваем страницу
  $page++;
} while($members['response']['count'] > $offset + $limit );

foreach ($users as $n => $user) // ходим по юзерам
  if(@$user['deactivated']) // и забаненных
    unset($users[$n]); // удаляем

var_dump($users);
```

Протестил, поправил. Мне вернуло 7257 юзеров (и да, готовый массив - `$users`, а не `$members`).

Comment: http://lab.reaged.ru/getMembers.php - Вот результат выполнения
Изменил только:
while($members['response']['count'] > $page * $limit );

Comment: Выдает также не больше 1000 участников.

Comment: @ReaGedCorp , обновил ответ, пробуйте.

Comment: Отлично!! Все работает! ( http://lab.reaged.ru/getMembers.php )


А нельзя ли сразу проверять юзера, забанен он или нет, перед добавлением в общий массив? Это сократило бы время выполнения. Сейчас оно составляет 25.13 sec

Comment: @ReaGedCorp, так а количество проверок-то не изменится) Хотя...

Проверил, видимо, единственное что может помочь, это заменить `sleep(1)` на `usleep(334000)` - тогда будет ~15-16 сек. Основное время съедает отправка-получение-разбор запроса, по 1.5-2 сек, отсюда и время. Данных довольно много туда-сюда бегает.

Comment: А вообще зачем добавлять задержку?

Comment: @ReaGedCorp а про это @sergiks в соседнем ответе сказал. Лимит на 3 запроса в секунду. Хотя если у вас большая часть запросов гарантированно работает дольше 0.33 сек - можно и убрать, но с пониманием последствий. Еще можно заморочиться и проверять, мол, если шаг цикла работал меньше 0.33 сек - то ставить задержку в разницу времени. Но это - сами, ибо совсем другая история. Подскажу, что шаманить с `microtime(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Больше 1к участников: обычная разбивка-на-страницы. Почти получилось же, где конкретно застряли?

**Оптимизация 1**:  в секунду можно выполнять до трех запросов, поэтому можете вместо `sleep(1)` делать `usleep( 333333)` (1/3 c);

**Оптимизация 2**: есть клевый метод ВК API [`execute()`](https://vk.com/dev.php?method=execute), куда вы передаете JS-подобный код, который выполнится на стороне ВК и вам вернет результат. Что бы ни было внутри, это считается за один запрос. Можете сконструировать код, который сразу несколько раз подряд выполнит `getMembers()`. Так, за один запрос, вы сможете получить вместо 1тыс, скажем, сразу 10тыс пользователей. Списать код процедуры можете [у этого приложения](https://vk.com/compare_groups) (не мое).

Comment: Застрял на моменте объединения массивов. Т.е. мне при каждом запросе возвращается массив и его нужно объединить с предыдущим, но вот это я не понимаю как сделать.

Comment: [array_merge][1]

  [1]: http://php.net/array_merge